# ASP.NET Core 7 Web API validates token however controller still responds with 401 status

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-7.0

I have a project which consists of a Chrome extension as the frontend and an ASP.NET Core 7 Web API as the backend. The project is using Azure Entra ID for OAuth.

Using the extension, I am able to successfully retrieve a bearer token and pass it to the API. The API appears to fully validate the token however all responses from the controller are a 401 status.

Here is the `Program.cs` code related to the authentication / authorization:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
```

```
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseCors();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.MapControllers();
    app.Run();
```

And here is a barebones controller I setup to try and test the auth:

```
[Authorize]
[ApiController]
[Route("controller")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    public WeatherForecastController()
    {
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<string> Test()
    {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

Here is the output of the log (with tokens removed):

```
info: Microsoft.IdentityModel.LoggingExtensions.IdentityLoggerAdapter\[0\]
Microsoft.IdentityModel Version: 6.32.3.0. Date 10/06/2023 10:56:55. PII logging is ON, do not use in production. See https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII for details.
IDX10242: Security token: '{}' has a valid signature.
info: Microsoft.IdentityModel.LoggingExtensions.IdentityLoggerAdapter\[0\]
IDX10239: Lifetime of the token is valid.
info: Microsoft.IdentityModel.LoggingExtensions.IdentityLoggerAdapter\[0\]
IDX10234: Audience Validated.Audience: ''
info: Microsoft.IdentityModel.LoggingExtensions.IdentityLoggerAdapter\[0\]
IDX10245: Creating claims identity from the validated token: '{}'.
info: Microsoft.IdentityModel.LoggingExtensions.IdentityLoggerAdapter\[0\]
IDX10241: Security token validated. token: '{}'.
```

Comment: Error 401 is unauthorize.  Is route valid?  Where is error 401 being generated in server?  [Authorize] should allow access to the route.  So either your route is wrong or the body of message is not deserializing properly.  The ActionResult is the body/content of the request.  The Controller Base may be giving the error because the body is not proper.

Comment: The route is valid. If I take the [Authorize] tag out of the controller and make a request, everything works as expected and I get a response from the controller. As soon as I put the [Authorize] tag back on the controller, all requests fail with a 401 status despite the token showing as being validated in the logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to your description, you got 401 error when you add `[Authorize]` attribute while got correct response without the attribute, so we could surmise that the issue is related with the access token.

Please allow me to share my configuration in web api first. Except the code you shared, I have my configurations in appsettings.json like this:

```
"AzureAd": {
  "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
  "ClientId": "azure_ad_app_id",
  "ClientSecret": "client_secret",
  "Domain": "tenantId",
  "TenantId": "tenantId",
  //I used the same app to expose an API so in my sample the 2 azure_ad_app_id are the same.
  "Audience": "api://azure_ad_app_id"
},
```

Since I just use `[Authorize]` attribute, so no matter the token contains `roles` or `scope`, both of them are ok, that means the token we have is valid no matter we use auth code flow or client credential flow to generate it. In other words, if the token contains correct roles or correct scp, the token is valid. You might decode your token to check if it contained correct claims.

[image]

Let's see an example with client credential flow token. First I [exposed an api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-registration#expose-application-permissions-app-roles) with application type and add add api permission.

[image]

Then I used [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#first-case-access-token-request-with-a-shared-secret) to generate an access token.

[image]

With this token, I'm able to call this api.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. This led me down a rabbit hole that eventually resulted in me realizing it was not my Web API code that had an issue but rather how I am handling getting the authentication token on the front end.

The front end extension is using implicit grant flow which results in a token that does not contain the scope claim which is why the controller is returning a 401 error. 

I am now working on fixing the extension code to request the proper token. Just need to wrap my head around adding PKCE to keep the client secret hidden.